# C# When creating a table I get "incorrect syntax" error if my column / field name contains a "-" hyphen

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Below is a snippet of my code, when a table name contains a hyphen, I get the error below. How can I fix this? Thanks for the help.

[alt text http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/148/createtable.png](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/148/createtable.png)

ex = {"ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '-'."}

Comment: "It hurts when I do that" "Then don't do that" -- in other words, don't put hyphens in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[]` round the column name:

```
CREATE TABLE [test2] 
(cn VarChar(1024) NULL,
 [tutor-id] VarChar(1024) NULL)
```

Or preferably stick to column names which don't require special treatment...

Note that it's a *column* name which has a hyphen, not the *table* name.

Comment: Arguably, OP just said the table contains the hyphen, not the table *name* =)

Comment: @David: "when a table name contains a hyphen" seems pretty clear to me ;)

Comment: Thanks, I can't avoid the hyphen it's included in the data I receive, thanks all I'll try [table-id].

Answer (score 3):

Use `[tutor-id]`

Answer (score 3):

If you must, you might be able to work around this by setting the field name to `[tutor-id]` rather than `tutor-id`, but just renaming the field to `tutorId` is an approach i'd rather take.

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't like hyphens. Try enclosing tutor-id in square brackets: `[tutor-id]`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the hyphen by an underscore or enclose the name in [ and ].

Answer (score 1):

Try:

CREATE Table [test2] (
   [cn] varchar(1024) NULL,
   [tutor-id] varchar(1024) NULL
)